# Open the window, would you?

Tags: tag-questions

**Open the window, would you?**

Why isn't it 'wouldn't you'? The first part (open the window) is neither positive nor negative, an imperative, however, the question tag is negative in the following sentences.

Keep quiet, won’t you?

Sit down, won’t you?

But **why is it 'Open the window, would (without NOT) you?'**

[the source](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-28/session-1) is BBC Learning English

Edit: since there's a controversy whether it's a question tag or not, the suggested previous questions doesn't provide an answer to this question. The suggested question (and the answers to it) are in a more broad sense.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Imperative sentence and the following tag question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/232554/41273)

Comment: @Laurel it is, but it's not if it's an inverted question rather than a QT as stated in the answers which I'm not sure :)

Comment: There's usually no difference between request/demand ***Will you shut up!*** and ***Won't you shut up!*** - and by implication there's usually no difference in most similar contexts. Such usages are nothing to do with "tag questions".

Comment: Eddie's answer in Laurel's comment answers your question quite well.  Voting to close.

Comment: @orhantorun - Your link to the BBC covers your question and provides an answer.  See *section #3 Imperatives*.  It says it could be *Open the window, would you* or it could be *Open the window, wouldn't you.*  Either works.  I'm not sure why you link to a site that answers your question and then ask the question.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther My reason is too simple, as stated in the question, why is the one without 'not' is correct? As the first part of the sentence is not negative. Moreover, #3 only implies 'wouldn't' you' is possible. Read again: 'we use won't you? although other modal verbs can be used, such as will, would, can, and could.' Nothing about wouldn't you here. 'Such as' at the beginning makes 'would not' a possible option, it's not an explanation. It contradicts with the number 1 rule of q.tags; hence -probably- an exception.

Comment: Since there's a question that would have a yes/no answer, it doesn't make any difference. Will you do it, or won't you? Do I have to spank you or not?

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther btw there is no Eddie in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that "tag questions" often negate the assertion in order to get clear confirmation rather than just yes or no which would be ambiguous. As a tag question, Not!

tag question example: **You do go to school, don't you?**

Here it is just an action request with an affirmation, that might be just **omitting the tail word "mind"** as in ***"Would you mind opening the window?"*** or ***Open the window, would you (mind)?***

"Mind you" is a common British interjection and is polite way of saying something.

### Added:

This example has one purpose in common with tag questions that may have prompted this question.

It is a [rhetorical question](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rhetorical_question) that the negation will not be challenged.

- A question to which no answer is expected, often used for rhetorical effect.
- A question posed only for dramatic or **persuasive effect**.
- A question to which the asker **does not expect an answer**.

Answer (score 1):

Normal structure: *Would you open the window, please?*

Conversational switch around often used in speaking: *Open the window, would you?*

So, there we can see it is not a tag like the ones below:

- You never open the windows, do you?
- You wouldn't open the windows, would you? If there was child trying to get out?
- You would open the window for me, wouldn't you?

Would you x and Shall I x are used to ask for or offer to do something for someone:

*Would you open the window?* [asking]
*Shall I open the window?* [offering]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tag question (as usually understood). It is an invitation, with completely different semantics from a tag question.

Comment: thank you. they (https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-28/session-1) teach it under 'question tag' title. Why do they?

Comment: It seems that my view is not the only one. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) describes both kinds in the same article, referring to the kind you are asking about as "unbalanced".

Comment: Laurel says *It's a tag that is a question and many reliable sources call it a "question tag" (or "tag question"), so how is it not one?*

Comment: To me it is only superficially similar to what that article calls "balanced tag questions", with very different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simply an inverted request or invitation as Colin says.

> Would you open the window [for me]?

is the polite request meaning, *Open the window.*

Inverted it becomes -

> Open the window [for me], would you?

A version of your sentence that uses a *question tag* would be similar to,

> You sure open a lot of windows, don't you?

That's not really a question.  It's an observation that you are looking to verify or receive more information about.  The tag portion would merely be looking for a confirmation, per the BBC link.

Comment: thank you. they (https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-28/session-1) teach it under 'question tag' title. what is the reason?

Comment: @orhantorun It is not a *question tag*.  It is merely part of the sentence which changes the command, *Open the window*, into a request, *Would you open the window?*  That request is then inverted with the command up-front and the request at the end.

Comment: It's a tag that is a question and many reliable sources call it a "question tag" (or "tag question"), so how is it not one?

Comment: @Laurel - Per the BBC site, it is NOT *asking for more information about something, or  confirming something which we believe is true.*  It is merely being used to turn a command into a request.  Please provide a *reliable source* that refutes this before responding.

Comment: [Active English grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=i7GY2xHFkYcC&pg=PT31): "You use positive statements with positive question tags to show reactions" [Collins online](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/how-are-sentence-tags-used-in-english) prefers "sentence tags" but says that both are used: "[Sentence tags] are sometimes called question tags, but many sentences ending with a tag are not real questions. They are usually used to check that the listener agrees with what the speaker has said." I can provide more examples.

Comment: @Laurel - Thanks.  From the Collins site - *Tags are short additions that look like questions, used at the end of a declarative sentence.*  Maybe you're uncertain what a declarative sentence is?  *Bill likes apples,* is a declarative sentence.  I can add a question tag to that, *Bill likes apples, doesn't he?*  *Open the window,* is a not a declarative sentence.  It is a command.  I cannot add a question tag to it, *Open the window, don't you?*  No, that does not work.

Comment: See the bottom of the page: "After a command, a tag made with can, could, will, shall, or would makes an order more polite. *Make me a cup of tea, will you?*" (Though I would say it doesn't really make it sound polite.)

Comment: @Laurel - So the sentence, *Would you open the window for me?* is not a question tag?  Inverting that sentence creates a question tag?  Seems like something is missing.

Comment: There's no [tag](https://web.archive.org/web/20201126035218/https://www.lexico.com/web/20201126035218/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tag) (see Grammar definition) in "Would you open the window for me?". That's just a question (albeit one that expects you to not answer it and instead go and open the window).

Comment: @Laurel - Collin said it best - *This is not a tag question **(as usually understood)***.  I probably should have included that disclaimer.  If I had more time I would differentiate the BBC definition of *asking for more information about something, or confirming something which we believe is true* which is often set apart with a negative tag (i.e. don't you) and turning a command into a request which is most often tagged with a positive (i.e. will you).